# Printing values in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

In order to print values in Python 3 we use

```py
print(a, "ok", b)
```

How can we print valuesin Python 2?

Comment: Like that but without the `(` `)` and the `**`.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
print a, "ok", b
print "{} ok {}".format(a, b)
print "{a} ok {b}".format(a=a, b=b)
```